# javascript takes too long to perform, Makes viewers wait too long

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function change(element) {
  document.getElementById('imageReplace').src = element;
}

function change_1() {
  document.getElementById('1').style.background = '#111';
  document.getElementById('1').style.color = '#FFF';
  document.getElementById('1').style.cursor = 'auto';
  document.getElementById('2').style.background = '#FFC300';
  document.getElementById('2').style.color = '#FFF';
  document.getElementById('2').style.cursor = 'pointer';
  document.getElementById('3').style.background = '#FFC300';
  document.getElementById('3').style.color = '#FFF';
  document.getElementById('3').style.cursor = 'pointer';
}

function change_2() {
  document.getElementById('2').style.background = '#111';
  document.getElementById('2').style.color = '#FFF';
  document.getElementById('2').style.cursor = 'auto';
  document.getElementById('1').style.background = '#FFC300';
  document.getElementById('1').style.color = '#FFF';
  document.getElementById('1').style.cursor = 'pointer';
  document.getElementById('3').style.background = '#FFC300';
  document.getElementById('3').style.color = '#FFF';
  document.getElementById('3').style.cursor = 'pointer';
}

function change_3() {
  document.getElementById('3').style.background = '#111';
  document.getElementById('3').style.color = '#FFF';
  document.getElementById('3').style.cursor = 'auto';
  document.getElementById('1').style.background = '#FFC300';
  document.getElementById('1').style.color = '#FFF';
  document.getElementById('1').style.cursor = 'pointer';
  document.getElementById('2').style.background = '#FFC300';
  document.getElementById('2').style.color = '#FFF';
  document.getElementById('2').style.cursor = 'pointer';
}
```

```css
.row_1 {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="row_1">
  <button id="1" onclick="change('somepic.jpg'); change_1()">1</button>
  <button id="2" onclick="change('somepic2.jpg'); change_2()">2</button>
  <button id="3" onclick="change('somepic3.jpg'); change_3()">3</button>
 </div>
```

I'm kinda new here...
Just started my website and tried some javascript coding.

The funny thing is it works very well in Adobe Dreamweaver CS6 when opened in Firefox.

However, when it's placed in my website manager (How my website gets put on the internet), it works super slowly...

Please help. I suspect the code must be too long, but I've tried a lot of methods and it doesn't show the way I want it to...

As you may have guessed, I'm trying to make a button that changes style when clicked and the other buttons will get back to default styling...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's a lot of duplicate code...wait a sec

Comment: you have duplicate code, but that doesn't seems to be a problem for slowness, how big are your images?

Comment: for jQuery approach see this example: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/css_css.asp

Comment: No point in using jQuery here... it's even slower.

Comment: You can rather have one function and pass the necessary values as arguments (may be in an array) or use switch-case, instead of duplicating the code.

Comment: The repeated code is not the best solution yes, but his long loading times come from the images. They are just too big. Previewing in Dreamweaver and loading local images is fine, but downloading images of course takes longer.

Comment: That Javascript is in no way going to cause any kind of major slowdown which is so noticeable. As @hallleron pointed out it has to be the image sizes and load times. The code examples to stop the duplication will all benefit but not resolve your issue.

Answer (score 4):

Don't repeatedly use `document.getElementById()`. It makes no sense. Every time you do this, you're searching the DOM for the node.

So instead of this:

```
function change_3() {
  document.getElementById('3').style.background = '#111',
  document.getElementById('3').style.color = '#FFF',
  document.getElementById('3').style.cursor = 'auto'
}
```

do this

```
var three = document.getElementById('3');

function change_3() {
  three.style.background = '#111',
  three.style.color = '#FFF',
  three.style.cursor = 'auto'
}
```

Comment: I agree, but the heavy use of `document.getElementById()` can't be the main reason for the slow website.

Comment: Probably not, but with the info given, that's really the only thing that stands out.

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned you shouldn't repeatedly be using `document.getElementById()` to get the same element.
Also the commas should be semicolons and I think that using just a number as id isn't right either, but I could be mistaken on that part.

If I'm interpreting your code correctly, you're simply trying to set the clicked button to active and the others to inactive while also replacing an image.

Here's what I would do:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row_1">
  <button id="button1" class="button" data-image="somepic.jpg">1</button>
  <button id="button2" class="button" data-image="somepic2.jpg">2</button>
  <button id="button3" class="button" data-image="somepic3.jpg">3</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.row_1 {
  float: left;
}

.button {
  background: #ffc300;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button.active {
  background: #111;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: auto;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
  $('.button').on('click',function() {
    var $btn = $(this);
    var image = $btn.data('image');
    if (image) {
      change(image);
    }
    changeButton($btn);
  });
});

function change(element) {
  document.getElementById('imageReplace').src = element;
}

function changeButton($btn) {
  $('.button').not($btn).removeClass('active');
  if (!$btn.hasClass('active')) {
    $btn.addClass('active');
  }
}
```

**Edit**
I'm using jQuery since you tagged your question as such, even though you're not using any jQuery in your own code.

Comment: Wow, such great replies! Quick, too!

Comment: My images are quite big since I'm making a somewhat gallery/showcase page (?)... I've changed it to another simpler page for laziness sake...

Comment: Again, thanks! I'll be gladly to ask again if anything comes up again! Thank you very much, guys!